# XMLHttpRequest readyState is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I can't get any data with XMLHttpRequest, because its readyState returns 0. I have this code:

```
function chargerArrondissements() {
    var xhrArrond = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrArrond.onreadystatechange = chargerArrondCallback(xhrArrond);
    var lienDocArrond = 'PHP/script_load_arrondissements_get.php';
    xhrArrond.open('GET', lienDocArrond, true);
    console.log('Arrondissements chargés dans le fichier xml');
    xhrArrond.send(null);
}

function chargerArrondCallback(xhrArrond) {
    alert(xhrArrond.readyState);
}
```

The alert window shows 0. I also tried opening the XHR before setting the handler, but it still return 0. Now, the strange thing is that I have many XHRs on that page, and they all work very well, except that one, and I can't explain why.

Btw, my php file path is: `http://localhost/TP2/PHP/script_load_arrondissements_get.php` .

Also, you should know that this file returns a correct xml content.

This is what the console says about my request:
[image]

Anyone knows what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you inspected the request in the console?

Comment: Yes I have, but I'm not exactly sure I understand. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xhrArrond.onreadystatechange = chargerArrondCallback(xhrArrond);
```

You are calling your event handler function and assigning its return value (`undefined`) as the event handler.

Change it to:

```
xhrArrond.onreadystatechange = chargerArrondCallback;
```

… and then access the XHR object it is associated with using `this` inside the function.

Comment: Maybe I don't know how exactly to use 'this', but I tried:
console.log(this.xhrArrond); inside the chargerArrondCallback function and it returns undefined.

Comment: @ProgProsecutor — You use `this` *instead of` `xhrArround`, not as well as it.